# How to add any plugin to ckeditor manually?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, plugins

I'm trying to add a new plugin `ckwebspeech` in ckeditor module. Here is the [plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/ckwebspeech) which I want to add.

[image]

So, that the final editor will look like mentioned in screenshot. Is there any way to add this manually?

Comment: Does this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1793710) help?

Comment: But you your question is not saying what problem you are getting.

Comment: I was trying adding manually first, as there is one an option available to build your custom editor. above link will be the last option.

Comment: CodeNext, I mentioned in the last line " Is there any way to add ckwebspeech plugin manually in ckeditor drupal module? Plugin is attached above, if you click on link.

Comment: @SugandhKhanna I found another good tutorial on that http://margotskapacs.com/2014/05/adding-ckeditor-plugins-manually-in-drupal/. If you can state what you have tried or what method you supposed to have, it is easier for others answer the question :)

Comment: Every plugin to be added to the CKeditor are **Manual method** only..:( let me write the answer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual process is described on that plugin page itself, as you can see on the instruction page in first image(red circle.)

If you click that link which you have provided in your question, you can see the `Download` option on that page. If you click it will download and it will open up a new pop-up window.

[image]

**1.** As you can see in the image. Copy that file and paste to that path.

So, I did copy and paste at at `module/ckeditor/plugins/ckwebspeech`

**2.** Now second step says, put this code `config.extraPlugins = 'ckwebspeech';` So, I went to `admin/modules/ckeditor/config`. I did choose either Full or advanced, whichever my site is using. Clicked edit, went to `Advanced options` And paste the second step as shown in the step-2. Saved it ans clear the cache.

> [image]

**3.** Now again went to same place at described in step-2. Instead of `Advanced option` went to `Editor appearance` and move the `webSpeechSetting` and `webSpeechEnabled` button to the custom toolbar as shown in following image.

> [image]

**4.** Now if I scroll down further on the same page, I will have all option of the plugins then I enabled that plugin as shown in following image.(see second option which i checked). Saved cleared cache.

> [image]

**5.** Now went to any page where I can see my editor, and, it showed up in editor.

> [image]

Comment: Lot's of screenprints ... but ... interesting!